# Getting message info from Messages.app with AppleScript

Tags: applescript, imessage

I’m looking to get information about individual messages in chat threads in Messages.app.

I can get individual chat threads:

```
set firstChat to first chat
```

I can get everything I ever wanted to know about file transfers (media sent/received via iMessage):

```
get properties of the last file transfer whose direction is incoming
```

I can handle messages as they arrive (which is pretty magical):

```
on message received msg from bud
    processIncomingMessage(msg, bud)
end message received
```

I just can’t figure out how to get information about *individual messages*. I’ve pored over the dictionary for Messages.app. It’s been super helpful up until I reach `chat`, then it seems I can’t get more specific than a chat thread.

The incoming message handler is great, but it doesn’t give me anything interesting in the `message` parameter. I can’t even get an index of the message.

Have I missed something, or is it not possible to get information about individual messages?

---

I have officially declared “f**k it” and given up on finding an AppleScript-y way of getting messages. Everything I need is encased in glorious SQLite (`~/Library/Messages/chat.db`). Thank you all for your help, I couldn’t have done it without you, keep up the good work, etc. etc.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
tell application "Messages" to set lastmessage to subject of first text chat
```

Comment: That seems to do the trick. I’m still taking the SQLite route, but thanks for the reply.

Comment: I get this error message: "Messages got an error: Can’t get subject of last text chat."